# SQL Server or functionality in where condition

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL query where I want to get the rows with values "all" or "female" in [gender] column and value "A" in [group] column. If there are 2 rows with [group] = A and [gender] = all and the other [group] = A and [gender] = female I want to get only the row with [gender] = all. Now I use:

```
where group=A and (gender=all or gender=female)
```

But I get both rows

In the example table below I want to get only the row: `A        all`

But if I use the `where group=A and (gender=all or gender=female)` query I will get both rows for group A

**group    gender**

`A        all`

`A      female`

`B        all`

`C      female`

`C        all`

Comment: whats your full query? and add a sample table. it will make it easier to understand

Comment: The query is running as it should, but not as you expect it.

Comment: Please take some time to format your question so that it's easily readable.  Add sample data - add current output - add expected output - add what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to prioritize the various subsets of records you're looking at and then select only one record from each. From the wording of your question I assume there is some other field in the table on which you're "grouping" records together—in other words, a field whose every distinct value should produce at most one record in the result set whose `group` and `gender` values match your criteria. In the following example I've assumed that this field is called `Category`; if you share the actual schema of your table then I can improve the example, but this should suffice to illustrate the idea.

```
declare @SampleData table
(
    Category bigint,
    [Group] char(1),
    Gender varchar(16)
);
insert @SampleData values
    (1, 'A', 'Female'), -- include
    (2, 'B', 'Female'), -- exclude; wrong group
    (3, 'A', 'Female'), -- exclude; right group and gender but superseded by (3, 'A', 'All')
    (3, 'A', 'All'),    -- include
    (4, 'A', 'All'),    -- include
    (5, 'A', 'Male');   -- exclude; wrong gender

with PrioritizedData as
(
    select
        D.*,
        [Priority] = row_number() over (partition by D.Category order by case D.Gender when 'All' then 0 else 1 end)
    from
        @SampleData D
    where
        D.[Group] = 'A' and
        D.Gender in ('Female', 'All')
)
select * from PrioritizedData P where P.[Priority] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RANK()` window function with results grouped by `group` and ordered by `gender` (this works because `all` is alphabetically before `female` or `male`. If your ordering gets more complex than that, you'll have to look at another way to order them.

```
/* TEST DATA */
; WITH a AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS thegroup, 'all' AS gender UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS thegroup, 'all' AS gender UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS thegroup, 'female' AS gender UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' AS thegroup, 'all' AS gender UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' AS thegroup, 'female' AS gender UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C' AS thegroup, 'all' AS gender UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D' AS thegroup, 'female' AS gender
)
/* THE QUERY */    
SELECT b.* 
FROM (
    SELECT thegroup, gender, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY thegroup ORDER BY gender) AS rn /* Sets the ranked groups of 'thegroup' */
    FROM a
) b
WHERE b.rn = 1 /* Gets first group. */
    AND thegroup = 'A'
```

Comment: Also, can never go wrong listening to advice from Celko: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

data script

```
declare @data table ([group] char(1), [gender] varchar(16));
insert into @data values ('A', 'all'), ('A', 'female') ,('B', 'all') ,('C', 'female') ,('C', 'all');
```

query

```
select 
     [group]    =   [d].[group]
    ,[gender]   =   [x].[gender]
from 
    @data   as [d]
cross apply
    (
        select top 1 [gender] from @data where [group] = [d].[group] order by iif([gender] = 'all', 0, 1) asc   
    )       as [x]
group by
     [d].[group]
    ,[x].[gender];
```